# Where to find new firmware upgrades application on GNOME 3.18

Tags: gnome, upgrade, ppa, firmware, 15.10

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I read [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/09/gnome-3-18-release-new-features) that there is a new firmware upgrades application, but I can't seem to find it anywhere, so how do I find it? I have installed GNOME 3.18 from the [gnome3](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3) and [gnome3-staging](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging) PPAs. I understand that it may not have been installed due to the fact that an app it depends on is not available on Ubuntu, but I plan to find a way round that and would at least like to make a start by finding the firmware upgrades application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not installed by default on releases before 16.04.  You can load with `sudo apt-get install fwupd` then execute `fwupdate -s` to see if your hardware is supported.